# C++: Function that returns an enum

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, enums

I have declared the following enum in the header of my class:

```
class clsWString2
{


public:

    enum eTagType
    {
        TT_UNDEFINED,
        TT_RATEABSSPEED,
        TT_VOLUMELEVEL,
        TT_RATESPEED,
    };
```

Now I have created a private function in the cpp file:

```
eTagType clsWString2::wstringToTagType(wstring u)
{
     ...
}
```

This does not work.
The compiler tells me "eTagType is undefined".

Can somebody help, please?

The following works:

```
void clsWString2::wstringToTagType(wstring u, eTagType &uRetValue)
```

... but I don't like this kind of function, I prefer having the function return a value, and I would also like to know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: The type name would be `clsWString2::eTagType`.

Comment: You have **defined** the enumerated type in the **definition** of your class. That might or might not be in a header file, but where it occurs doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eTagType` enumeration is in the scope of the `clsWString2` class, so you have to tell the compiler it's scope:

```
clsWString2::eTagType clsWString2::wstringToTagType(wstring u) { ... }
```

Comment: And the reason it works when `eTagType` is a parameter is that parameters *are* evaluated in the scope of the class. Seems inconsistent but not if you understand what the parser has to work with.

Comment: I love you, you are great! :-)